# Undefined variable $store in Joomla.php on line 56 - CRM_Core_Permission_Joomla error

Tags: joomla, error, php, logs

I am experiencing an issue with Joomla integration while using CiviCRM. I am getting the following error on line 56 of the "Joomla.php" file:

PHP Warning: Undefined variable $store in /home/userxxx/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Permission/Joomla.php on line 56

[image]

This error indicates that the variable `$store` is not defined when trying to set the `$api_key` variable. However, I have noticed that I haven't previously defined the `$store` variable.

Relevant code snippet:

```
$api_key = CRM_Utils_Request::retrieve('api_key', 'String', $store, FALSE, NULL, 'REQUEST');
```

[image]

I am seeking assistance with resolving this issue. How should I properly define the `$store` variable?

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Best regards,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just a warning, not an error, but looks like a problem that should be fixed, you could [report it on Gitlab](https://lab.civicrm.org/groups/dev/-/issues/) and maybe even fix it yourself.

I think `$store` could probably not be passed at all since the default is NULL (the other params after it are also default), but maybe there is some reason to set it NULL first, as it is [in other places.](https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Acivicrm%2Fcivicrm-core%20CRM_Utils_Request%3A%3Aretrieve%20%24store&type=code)

Comment: It was refactored here causing the bug: https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/commit/906e5a456c763b36052eef0a462eb6b860f1eddd. As noted I would just remove the extra params `$api_key    = CRM_Utils_Request::retrieve('api_key', 'String');` and the $store assignment lower down.